# Describe DB Instances with AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-step-functions

I've tried to use DescribeDBInstances with AWS Step Function, and these parameters :

```
{
  "DBInstanceIdentifier.$": "$.GetResources.ResourceTagMappingList[0].ResourceARN"
}
```

When I launch the execution, I have this error :

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'DescribeDBInstances' (entered at the event id #7). The Parameters '{\"DBInstanceIdentifier\":\"arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:db:database-1\"}' could not be used to start the Task: [The field \"DBInstanceIdentifier\" is not supported by Step Functions]"
}
```

However, the parameter "DBInstanceIdentifier" is referenced in the attached documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBInstances.html

Can you tell me what's wrong ? And what can I do ?

The only solution I have in mind is to use an AWS Lambda function...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. We are more than happy to then help.

Comment: Also - what are you trying to really do? https://xyproblem.info

Comment: I try to have the complete identifier of my RDS database with a template name. For example, my RDS Identifier is database-123456 and I want to get the full name with "database" input. 
This is why I thought the action DescribeDBInstances was a good one but I'm actually facing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter is `DbInstanceIdentifier` and not `DBInstanceIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

If you use the DescribeDBInstances without parameters, you can have all informations about all your instances. You can add a "Pass" block with JSON Path Regex and find what you want.